# Anyone know the mechanism of warp retirement in nvidia products(Kepler)?

Tags: c, cuda, nvidia

I am talking about nvidia GPUs with compute capability 3.5 (GK110):

On each GPU core, there are at most 64 active warps, how the hardware handles warp retirements? can warps from different grid blocks or even streams work concurrently on a single core of a GPU (by core I mean multiprocessor, since they are estentially the core of a multi-core GPU)?

Can a core retires finished warps quickly from a stream and load other warps from maybe other stream to the same core?

The reason why I asked this is because there are hard decisions to make:

(1) I can write code to launch many threads from different streams, and about 2/3 of the warps launched will basically do nothing and get quick retirements.

OR:

(2) I can write code to launch exactly the number of threads that needed, but each thread will consists of very heavy indexing computations (through solving several indexing equations, the ammount of computation involved to just compute correct index will be just as much as, if not more, the real computation in (1)).

So if GK110 can retire empty warps quickly and replaces them with new warps then (1) will be better than (2) because it can avoid unncessary indexing computation completely.

So far trivial case test show the two works about the same, but I am not sure about whether (1) could be better in non-trival cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On each GPU core, there are at most 64 active warps.  How does the hardware handle warp retirements? Can warps from different grid blocks or even streams work concurrently on a single core of a GPU (by core I mean multiprocessor, since they are estentially the core of a multi-core GPU)?

Yes, warps from different threadblocks can be co-resident and ready to execute on a single SM.   These different threadblocks could be from the same kernel or different kernels, from different streams.  Thread blocks from different kernels executing concurrently is described [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution).

> Can a core retire finished warps quickly from a stream and load other warps from maybe other stream to the same core?

Yes.  The division of work is handled first by threadblock, before the assignment of warps occurs.  First a threadblock gets scheduled on an SM, then the process of selecting warps to execute occurs.  As long as there are available threadblock slots on an SM (and no other  limiters to scheduling, such as shared memory or register usage), new threadblocks from any available kernel can get scheduled on a cc 3.5 SM.